# Prevent tmux from displaying "Activity in window n"

Tags: configuration, tmux

I'd like to prevent tmux from flashing an "Activity in window n" message when there's activity in a non active window. I'd like the only indication of background activity to be the window title color change I have configured.

Relative configuration file lines I have currently:

```
set status on
setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity on
set -g visual-bell on
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to tmux source code (version 1.8 at hand) (`server_window_check_activity()`, server-window.c), relevant option is `visual-activity` which you currently have set to `on`:

```c
if (options_get_number(&s->options, "visual-activity")) {
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH(&clients); i++) {
        c = ARRAY_ITEM(&clients, i);
        if (c == NULL || c->session != s)
            continue;
        status_message_set(c, "Activity in window %u",
        winlink_find_by_window(&s->windows, w)->idx);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Same function, a bit above:

```c
if (!options_get_number(&w->options, "monitor-activity"))
    return (0);
```

So you may want to try changing `monitor-activity` too.

**EDIT 2:**
You could always write a patch ;)

Comment: Changing to `set -g visual-activity off` worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g visual-activity off
```

Right now you have this set to `on`, which is why you see *Activity in window N*.

Answer (score 1):

In `tmux=2.2`, this worked for me:

```
setw -g monitor-activity on
set-option -g bell-action none
```

(but `set -g visual-activity off` as suggested above did not)